# How do I retrieve and assign a textbox value?

Tags: javascript

I need the Billing section to be filled automatically after the checkbox is checked.

If not checked, then Billing Info should be empty. So far, my code is not working.

````
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Shipping Information</legend>
        <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipName" id = "shippingName"
        required><br/>

        <label for ="shiipingZip">Zip code:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipZip" id = "shiippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
      </fieldset>

        <input type = "checkbox" id = "same" name = "same" onchange="billingFunction()"/>
        <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

        <fieldset> 
          <legend>Billing Information</legend>
          <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "billName" id = "billingName" required><br/>
          <label for = "billingZip">Zip code:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "billZip" id = "billingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
        </fieldset>
          <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/>
</form>

```HTML CODE```

```JavaScript Code```

function billingFunction(){
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
    var shipName1 = document.getElementById('shippingName').shipName; 
    var shipZip1 = document.getElementById('shippingZip').shipZip;
    document.getElementById('billingName').billName = shipName1;
    document.getElementById('billingZip').billZip = shipZip1;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('billingName').billName = "";
    document.getElementById('billingZip').billZip = "";
      }
}

```JavaScript Code```
````

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong syntax to get value, change

```
var shipName1 = document.getElementById('shippingName').shippingName;
```

to

```
var shipName1 = document.getElementById('shippingName').value;
```

```js
function billingFunction(){
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
    var shipName1 = document.getElementById('shippingName').value; 
    
    var shipZip1 = document.getElementById('shiippingZip').value;
    document.getElementById('billingName').value = shipName1;
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = shipZip1;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('billingName').value = "";
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = "";
      }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Shipping Information</legend>
        <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipName" id = "shippingName"
        required><br/>

        <label for ="shiipingZip">Zip code:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipZip" id = "shiippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
      </fieldset>

        <input type = "checkbox" id = "same" name = "same" onchange="billingFunction()"/>
        <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

        <fieldset> 
          <legend>Billing Information</legend>
          <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "billName" id = "billingName" required><br/>
          <label for = "billingZip">Zip code:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "billZip" id = "billingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
        </fieldset>
          <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use d`ocument.GetElementById().value` also you have a type @ `shiipingZip`

```js
function billingFunction(){
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
    var shipName1 = document.getElementById('shippingName').value; 
    var shipZip1 = document.getElementById('shippingZip').value;
    document.getElementById('billingName').value = shipName1;
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = shipZip1;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('billingName').value = "";
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = "";
      }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Shipping Information</legend>
        <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipName" id = "shippingName"
        required><br/>

        <label for ="shiipingZip">Zip code:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipZip" id = "shippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
      </fieldset>

        <input type = "checkbox" id = "same" name = "same" onchange="billingFunction()"/>
        <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

        <fieldset> 
          <legend>Billing Information</legend>
          <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "billName" id = "billingName" required><br/>
          <label for = "billingZip">Zip code:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "billZip" id = "billingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
        </fieldset>
          <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/>
</form>
```